# How do I break up and display only 1 of three variants at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I'm looking to build a multi-step product selector using tabs. I'm looking to display on variant per tab but can't find a way to break up variants to display them individually.

I have tried posting the code bellow multiple times (one in each tab) but this makes each selection "stuck". Yes I know this would of led to issues but I was just trying to make the code work.

```
        <div class="product-size  option-{{ option | handle }} {{ product_options }}">
            <span class="option-label">{{ option }}:</span>
            <div class="select-wrapper-sm">
                <select class="form-control input-sm size-variants">
                    {% for name in option_names %}
                        <option {% if selected_value == name %}selected="selected"{% endif %} value="{{ name | handle | downcase | escape }}">{{ name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            {% if product_options == 'swatches' %}
                <ul class="{% if option_title contains 'color' %}color-list{% else %}size-list{% endif %}" data-index="{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                    {% for name in color_image %}
                        {%- assign title = name | split:':' | first | replace:'!__!','' -%}
                        {%- assign img_src = name | split:':' | last -%}
                        <li  {% if selected_value == title %}class="active"{% endif %}>
                            {% if option_title contains 'color' %}<a href="#" data-tooltip="{{ title }}" data-placement="top" title="{{ title }}" data-value="{{ title | handle | escape }}" data-image="{{ img_src }}"><span class="value"><img src="{% if settings.product_previews_colors_variants %}{{ img_src }}{% else %}{{ title | handle | prepend:'color-' | append: '.png' | file_url | downcase }}{% endif %}" alt=""></span></a>{% else %}<a href="#" data-value='{{ title | handle | downcase | escape }}'><span class="value">{{ title | escape }}</span></a>{% endif %}
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

Currently the whole product form is being displayed with this code

```
<div class="product-actions product-id-{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }} {% if product.variants.size == 1 and quick_view == 'yes' %}product-no-options no-border{% endif %}">
            {% form 'product', product %}
                {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_management == "shopify" and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_quantity < 1 and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_policy == "continue" %}
                <input type="hidden" name="properties[{{ 'general.theme.status' | t }}]" value="{{ 'general.theme.pre_order' | t }}">
                {% endif %}
                {% if product.metafields.c_f.line_properties != blank %}
                    {{ product.metafields.c_f.line_properties }}
                {% endif %}
                {% include 'product-options-form' design:'default' %}
                {% if product.available %}
                <div class="product-actions-row">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <div class="product-qty">
                            <div class="qty qty-changer">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="text" class="qty-input" name="quantity" value="1" data-min="1" {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_management == "shopify" and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_quantity > 0 and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_policy == 'deny' %}data-max="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_quantity }}"{% endif %}>
                                    <input type="button" value="+" class="increase">
                                    <input type="button" value="-" class="decrease">
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-stock-dynamic {% unless product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_management == "shopify" and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_quantity > 0 and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_policy == 'deny'  %}hidden{% endunless %} stock-dynamic">{% if product_inventory_count %}max <b>{% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_management == "shopify" and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_quantity }}{% endif %}</b> {{ 'general.theme.itemss' | t }}{% endif %}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        {% capture status %}{{ 'general.theme.add_to_cart' | t }}{% endcapture %}
                        {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_management == "shopify" and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_quantity < 1 and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_policy == "continue" %}
                            {% capture status %}{{ 'general.theme.pre_order' | t }}{% endcapture %}
                        {% endif %}
                        <div class="product-actions-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-lg js-add-to-cart-product-page" data-product-handle="{{ product.handle }}"  data-variant-id="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}" title="{{ status }}"><span>{{ status }}</span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-actions-link">
                        {% if quick_view == 'yes' %}{% assign position = 'bot' %}{% else %}{% assign position = 'right' %}{% endif %}
                        {% include 'product-card-and-page-actions' position:position %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if section.settings.dynamic_checkout_button %}
                    <style>
                       .shopify-payment-button__more-options {
                            display: none;
                        }
                       .shopify-payment-button__button {
                           outline: none;
                           border-radius: 0;
                           text-transform: uppercase;
                           background: #d3fbc9;
                           color: #FFFFFF;
                           padding: 9px 35px 11px;
                           font-weight: 500;
                           line-height: 32px;
                           border: 0;
                           color: black;
                           font-weight: bold;
                       }
                       .shopify-payment-button__button--unbranded:hover:not([disabled]){
                           background: black !important;
                           color: #FFFFFF !important;
                       }
                    </style>
                    {{ form | payment_button }}
                    {% if section.settings.safe_checkout_image_yes %}
                        <br />
                        <h4>{{ settings.checkout_popup_guaranteed_caption }}</h4>
                        <img src="{% if section.settings.safe_checkout_image != blank %}{{ section.settings.safe_checkout_image | img_url:'master' }}{% else %}{{ 'guaranteed.png' | asset_url }}{% endif %}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endform %}
        </div>
```

which uses `{% include 'product-options-form' design:'default' %}` to display the following code

```
<div class="product-options id_{{ product.id }} {{ product_options }} {% if product.variants.size == 1 %}product-no-options no-border{% endif %}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}">
    {% unless product.options.size == 1 and product.options.first == 'Title' %}
    {%- assign index = 0 -%}
    {% for option in product.options %}
        {%- assign option_names = '' -%}
        {%- assign option_title = option | downcase -%}
        {%- assign index = forloop.index0 -%}
        {%- assign selected_value = '' -%}
        {%- assign color_images = '' -%}
        {%- assign color_image = '' -%}
        {% for variant in product.variants %}
            {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
                {% assign selected_value = variant.options[index] %}
            {% endif %}
            {%- assign img_url = variant.image.src |  img_url: '1024x1024' -%}
            {%- assign option_names = option_names | append:variant.options[index] | append:'<>' -%}
            {%- assign color_images = color_images | append : img_url  | append:'<>' -%}
            {%- assign check_color_name = '!__!' | append:variant.options[index] | append:'!__!' -%}
            {% unless color_image contains check_color_name %}
            {%- assign color_image = color_image | append:'!__!' | append:variant.options[index] | append:'!__!:' | append:img_url  | append:'<>' -%}
            {% endunless %}
        {% endfor %}
        {%- assign color_images = color_images | split:'<>' | uniq -%}
        {%- assign option_names = option_names | split:'<>' | uniq -%}
        {%- assign color_image = color_image | split:'<>' | uniq -%}
        <div class="product-size  option-{{ option | handle }} {{ product_options }}">
            <span class="option-label">{{ option }}:</span>
            <div class="select-wrapper-sm">
                <select class="form-control input-sm size-variants">
                    {% for name in option_names %}
                        <option {% if selected_value == name %}selected="selected"{% endif %} value="{{ name | handle | downcase | escape }}">{{ name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            {% if product_options == 'swatches' %}
                <ul class="{% if option_title contains 'color' %}color-list{% else %}size-list{% endif %}" data-index="{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                    {% for name in color_image %}
                        {%- assign title = name | split:':' | first | replace:'!__!','' -%}
                        {%- assign img_src = name | split:':' | last -%}
                        <li  {% if selected_value == title %}class="active"{% endif %}>
                            {% if option_title contains 'color' %}<a href="#" data-tooltip="{{ title }}" data-placement="top" title="{{ title }}" data-value="{{ title | handle | escape }}" data-image="{{ img_src }}"><span class="value"><img src="{% if settings.product_previews_colors_variants %}{{ img_src }}{% else %}{{ title | handle | prepend:'color-' | append: '.png' | file_url | downcase }}{% endif %}" alt=""></span></a>{% else %}<a href="#" data-value='{{ title | handle | downcase | escape }}'><span class="value">{{ title | escape }}</span></a>{% endif %}
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endunless %}
    <script>
        var product_options_{{ product.id }} = [];
        {%- assign options = product.options -%}
        {% for option in options %}
        {%- assign option_index = forloop.index0 -%}
        {% for variant in product.variants %}
        {%- assign params = variant.options -%}
        product_options_{{ product.id }}{% for name in params %}{% if forloop.index0 > option_index  %}{% continue %}{% endif %}['{{ params[forloop.index0]|handle|strip|downcase}}']{% endfor %}=[];
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for variant in product.variants %}
        {%- assign attributes = 'price,compare_at_price,id,image,inventory_quantity,inventory_management,inventory_policy,sku' | split:',' -%}
        {% for attribute in attributes %}
        product_options_{{ product.id }}{% for option in variant.options %}['{{ variant.options[forloop.index0] |handle|strip|downcase }}']{% endfor %}['{{ attribute|downcase }}']='{% if attribute == 'image'%}{% unless variant.image.src contains 'products' %}{{ product.featured_image |  img_url: '1024x1024' }}{% else %}{{ variant.image.src |  img_url: '1024x1024' }}{% endunless %}{% else %}{{ variant[attribute] }}{% endif %}';
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </script>
    {% if design == 'creative' %}</div>{% endif %}

{% if design == 'default' %}</div>{% endif %}

<script>
    {% assign product_id = product.id %}
    product_id = {{ product.id }}
    options_product_id = $('.product-options.id_'+product_id);
    $options_{{ product_id }} = $('.product-options.id_{{ product_id }}');
    $select_{{ product_id }} = $('select',$options_{{ product_id }});
    $ul_{{ product_id }} = $('ul',$options_{{ product_id }});


    function updateSelectOptionsDisabling_{{ product_id }}(){
        $('option',$select_{{ product_id }}.not(':first')).attr("disabled","disabled");
        for(a in product_options_{{ product_id }}[$select_{{ product_id }}.first().val()]){
            $('option[value='+a+']',$select_{{ product_id }}).removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
            for(b in product_options_{{ product_id }}[$select_{{ product_id }}.first().val()][a]){
                $('option[value='+b+']',$select_{{ product_id }}).removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
            }
        }
    }

    /*function currencyUpdate(){
        Currency.convertAll(shopCurrency, jQuery('.selected-currency').text());
    }*/

    function removeAbsentOption_{{ product_id }}($variant,current,$ul,$this_a){
        _this=$this_a;
        $inventory_management = $variant['inventory_management'];
        $inventory_policy = $variant['inventory_policy'];
        $inventory_quantity = $variant['inventory_quantity']
        if (($inventory_management != 'shopify') ||
                ($inventory_management == 'shopify' && $inventory_policy == 'continue') ||
                ($inventory_management == 'shopify' && $inventory_quantity > 0))
        {
            $('a[data-value=' + current + ']', $ul).parent().removeClass('absent-option');

        }
    };

    function showAvailableOptions_{{ product_id }}(first_option_only,last_option_only)
    {

        first_option_only = typeof first_option_only !== 'undefined' ?  first_option_only : false;
        last_option_only = typeof last_option_only !== 'undefined' ?  last_option_only : false;
        if(first_option_only)
        {
            $a = $('a', $ul_{{ product_id }}.first());
        } else if(last_option_only)
        {
            $('li',$ul_{{ product_id }}.last()).addClass("absent-option");
            $a = $('a', $ul_{{ product_id }}.last());
        } else
        {
            $('li',$ul_{{ product_id }}).addClass("absent-option");
            $a = $('a', $ul_{{ product_id }}.not(':first'));
        }
        $a.each(function () {
            current = $(this).data('value');
            _this = $(this);
            for (size in product_options_{{ product_id }})
            {
                if(!first_option_only || last_option_only){
                    size=$('li.active a',$ul_{{ product_id }}.first()).data('value');
                }
                if($ul_{{ product_id }}.length == 3){
                    flag_ignore_selection = false;
                    for (color in product_options_{{ product_id }}[size])
                    {
                        if(last_option_only){
                            color=$('li.active a',$ul_{{ product_id }}.not(':first').not(':last')).data('value');
                        }
                        for (material in product_options_{{ product_id }}[size][color])
                        {
                            switch (_this.closest('ul').data('index')) {
                                case 0:
                                    if (product_options_{{ product_id }}[current] != undefined && product_options_{{ product_id }}[current][color] != undefined && product_options_{{ product_id }}[current][color][material] != undefined) {
                                        removeAbsentOption_{{ product_id }}(product_options_{{ product_id }}[current][color][material],current,$ul_{{ product_id }},_this);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    if (product_options_{{ product_id }}[size] != undefined && product_options_{{ product_id }}[size][current] != undefined && product_options_{{ product_id }}[size][current][material] != undefined) {

                                        removeAbsentOption_{{ product_id }}(product_options_{{ product_id }}[size][current][material],current,$ul_{{ product_id }},_this);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    if (product_options_{{ product_id }}[size] != undefined && product_options_{{ product_id }}[size][color] != undefined && product_options_{{ product_id }}[size][color][current] != undefined) {
                                        removeAbsentOption_{{ product_id }}(product_options_{{ product_id }}[size][color][current],current,$ul_{{ product_id }},_this);
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if($ul_{{ product_id }}.length == 2)
                {
                    for (color in product_options_{{ product_id }}[size]) {
                        switch (_this.closest('ul').data('index')) {
                            case 0:
                                if (product_options_{{ product_id }}[current] != undefined && product_options_{{ product_id }}[current][color] != undefined) {
                                    removeAbsentOption_{{ product_id }}(product_options_{{ product_id }}[current][color], current, $ul_{{ product_id }},_this);
                                }
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                if (product_options_{{ product_id }}[size] != undefined && product_options_{{ product_id }}[size][current] != undefined) {
                                    removeAbsentOption_{{ product_id }}(product_options_{{ product_id }}[size][current], current, $ul_{{ product_id }},_this);
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (product_options_{{ product_id }}[current] != undefined) {
                        removeAbsentOption_{{ product_id }}(product_options_{{ product_id }}[current],current,$ul_{{ product_id }},_this);
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    function renderSwatches_{{ product_id }}()
    {
        showAvailableOptions_{{ product_id }}(); //2nd and 3rd
        showAvailableOptions_{{ product_id }}(true); //1st only
        $('li.active.absent-option',$ul_{{ product_id }}).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active').siblings().not('.absent-option').first().addClass('active');
        });
        showAvailableOptions_{{ product_id }}(false,true); //1st only
        $('li.active.absent-option',$ul_{{ product_id }}).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active').siblings().not('.absent-option').first().addClass('active');
        });
    }

    $(function($) {
        {% unless product_options == 'swatches' %}updateSelectOptionsDisabling_{{ product_id }}();{% endunless %}
        $select_{{ product_id }}.first().addClass('first');
        $ul_{{ product_id }}.first().addClass('first');
        $select_{{ product_id }}.change(function(){
            {% unless product_options == 'swatches' %}updateSelectOptionsDisabling_{{ product_id }}();{% endunless %}
            if($(this).hasClass('first'))
            {
                for (var first_option_to_select in product_options_{{ product_id }}[$select_{{ product_id }}.first().val()])break;
                $('option',$select_{{ product_id }}.not(':first')).removeAttr("selected");
                $('option[value='+first_option_to_select+']',$select_{{ product_id }}.not(':first')).attr("selected","selected");
            }
            updateData('select',product_id,options_product_id);
            Currency.convertAll('{{ shop.currency }}', Currency.cookie.read());
        })
        {% if product_options == 'swatches' %}

        $('a',$ul_{{ product_id }}).click(function(e){
            _this = $(this);
            if(!_this.parent().hasClass('absent-option')){
                if (!_this.parent('li').is('.active')){
                    _this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
                    _this.parent('li').addClass('active');
                }
                renderSwatches_{{ product_id }}();
                $this=$('ul.color-list:first > li.active:first > a:first',$options_{{ product_id }});
                if($this.data('image')){
                    var $image = $('.main-image img',$ul_{{ product_id }});
                    imgSrc = $this.data('image');
                    var newImg = document.createElement("img");
                    newImg.src = imgSrc;
                    newImg.onload = function () {
                        $image.attr('src', imgSrc);
                        $image.attr('data-zoom-image', imgSrc);
                    }
                }
                updateData('ul > li.active > a',{{ product_id }},$options_{{ product_id }});
                Currency.convertAll('{{ shop.currency }}', Currency.cookie.read());
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        })

        renderSwatches_{{ product_id }}();
        {% endif %}
    });
</script>




{{ 'custom.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

Within there I can kinda of see that this code is what displays the variants but I can't figure out how to break up each variant to be able to display them individually.

```
        <div class="product-size  option-{{ option | handle }} {{ product_options }}">
            <span class="option-label">{{ option }}:</span>
            <div class="select-wrapper-sm">
                <select class="form-control input-sm size-variants">
                    {% for name in option_names %}
                        <option {% if selected_value == name %}selected="selected"{% endif %} value="{{ name | handle | downcase | escape }}">{{ name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            {% if product_options == 'swatches' %}
                <ul class="{% if option_title contains 'color' %}color-list{% else %}size-list{% endif %}" data-index="{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                    {% for name in color_image %}
                        {%- assign title = name | split:':' | first | replace:'!__!','' -%}
                        {%- assign img_src = name | split:':' | last -%}
                        <li  {% if selected_value == title %}class="active"{% endif %}>
                            {% if option_title contains 'color' %}<a href="#" data-tooltip="{{ title }}" data-placement="top" title="{{ title }}" data-value="{{ title | handle | escape }}" data-image="{{ img_src }}"><span class="value"><img src="{% if settings.product_previews_colors_variants %}{{ img_src }}{% else %}{{ title | handle | prepend:'color-' | append: '.png' | file_url | downcase }}{% endif %}" alt=""></span></a>{% else %}<a href="#" data-value='{{ title | handle | downcase | escape }}'><span class="value">{{ title | escape }}</span></a>{% endif %}
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm looking to just brake them up so i can style them individually with tabs. I can manage all the rest by studying more. This has just stumped me.

I was able to find this code which outputs what I need but I can't seem to make them clickable to make them an option

```
{% for option in product.options %}
{% if option == 'Size' %}

 {% assign index = forloop.index0 %}
 {% assign sizelist = '' %}
 {% assign size = '' %}

 {% for variant in product.variants %}

    {% capture size %}
    {{ variant.options[index] }}
    {% endcapture %}

    {% unless sizelist contains size %}

       <span>{{ size }}</span>

       {% capture tempList %}
          {{sizelist | append: size | append: ' '}}
       {% endcapture %}
          {% assign sizelist = tempList %}
       {% endunless %}

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a loop through product.variants object:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
What you need to do with variant.
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I did a bit of searching with what you posted. I was able to find some code to output the information I need but I can't seem to make them clickable. Any ideas? I edited the original post to show the code I found at the end of it.